# PowerShell Modules - Where to store custom built modules and how to import them using profile.ps1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise, import-module

I'm a little confused about where to store my custom Powershell modules.

Here's an example of my `Utility.psm1`

```
New-Module -Name 'Utility' -ScriptBlock {
    function New-File($filename)
    {
        if(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($filename))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType File "$filename"
        } else {
            Write-Error "function touch requires filename as a parameter"
        }
    }

    function Change-DirectoryUp($number)
    {
        for($i=0; $i -lt $number; $i++)
        {
            if((pwd).Path -eq 'C:\') { break } else { cd .. }
        }
    }

    function Get-EnabledWindowsFeatures()
    {
        $features = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online
        $features | ? {$_.State -eq 'Enabled'} | select FeatureName
    }
}
```

If I want to import this module every time I open Powershell or Powershell ISE, how do I do it? Does it matter where I store `Utility.ps1`? I would like to avoid having to pass the full path to this file... but I'm worried using relative pathing would rely on the "Start-In" path.

I noticed there is a variable called `$env:PSModulePath`, but the path to the directory does not exist in my C: drive.

Should I create that directory and store them in there? If I do that, how do import the modules?

Comment: If you always want it to load into your session, use profiles.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 If I put all the code I have into my profile, it gets really really messy. I was hoping of using profiles as a way of grouping certain code and abstraction

Comment: That doesn't negate my statement... Just write a script with functions and dot-source it into your profile, or if you want, create a module out of it and utilize `Import-Module`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Is there any difference between dot sourcing a file with functions and running `Import-Module` after wrapping it in `New-Module`?.... I still can't figure that one out

Comment: Only if your file is loading binaries, running pre-condition scripts, relying on versioning, etc.  If it's just a static script with a psm1 extension, might as well dot-source it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - also hiding functions/variables/aliases.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Ok, so you're saying just remove the `New-Module` and dot source it. Yeah.. that works too. The only down side is you can't list what you've imported via `Get-Module *`

Comment: @KolobCanyon `Get-ChildItem -Path Function:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this is to keep a library folder for all my psm1 modules together with my scripts, and reuse that every time I write a new script. You can use the $myInvocation variable for this as it is relative to where the script file you're running is located. What I have done is have the following structure:

```
C:\Your\Path\To\Script\YourScript.ps1
C:\Your\Path\To\Script\Libraries\allYourPsmModules.psm1
```

I have a module that is called Import-Libraries.psm1 that is stored under the Libraries folder, containing the following code:

```
Function Global:Import-Libraries {    
param (
    [string] $LibrariesPath
)    
foreach ($module in (Get-ChildItem -Path "$LibrariesPath./*.psm1" -File)) {
    Import-Module ($module).FullName -Force
    }
}
```

Your script then needs to begin with the following:

```
$scriptDir = (split-path -parent -path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Import-module $scriptDir\Libraries\Import-Libraries.psm1
Import-Libraries .\Libraries
```

What these three lines do is that $scriptDir becomes a relative path so it doesn't matter where you store your script. I then import the module called 'Import-Modules' and after that I run that module on the Libraries folder. The module called Import-Libraries will always import all libraries that I have under the folder Libraries, so adding new libraries will always be done automatically.